# How can I fix this Headless Exception?

Tags: swing, user-interface, exception, debugging, headless

[This is a class that tells java to load and display a picture in my directory, it looks like the display function (which makes a picture popup GUI) is making a headless exception.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ir9Sz.png)
[This is the main spring boot application being ran](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oYKcC.png)
[This class tells the main what to do , all works fine until calling the load function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T2BM9.png)
[This is the error message, the error occurs when calling the load function, which calls the display function.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Rlgt.png)
I am creating a program that creates an image popup. But a headless exception resulted when I run the GUI portion of the program. Could this have to do with having a bad spring boot layout, or coding problems with the display function? Please help me with getting rid of this exception. Thank you all so much!

I tried to find the source of the error, which is the headless exception. But I have no idea how to fix it.

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors). Also, take the [tour] and visit the [help] and especially read [ask].

Comment: Some configurations are headless, for example [Windows Subsystem for Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install) (WSL). Pardon me, but I did not see any details, in your question, about your configuration. Did I miss something?